# How to get ApplicationContext in other project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, javassist

I have two spring projects, and I want to get the applicationContext object of the other project in one of the projects. How should I do it?

I want to use asm to enhance the SpringApplication class, but the jvm runtime doesn't support adding fields and methods (except dcevm, but I'm using hotspot), so I thought about modifying the jar file, but I can't modify it.

Would it be a good solution if I use jmx to do it?
I tried to use jmx but he can't expose ApplicationContext object.

I tried to use jni method to achieve it.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea for multiple reasons, security being the most important one.

Comment: It's like this, I just want to implement a hot-deployed plugin, so I need the ApplicationContext object to refresh the context object.